# no such file to load: pony (gem pathing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, pony

Working in Windows 7, Rail 3.2.8.
Seems like I am missing a config step somewhere.

Trying to get Pony.options loaded via my environment.rb file.

The environment.rb contains:

```
require "rubygems"
require "pony"
```

but I get this error after starting rails server:

```
no such file to load -- pony (LoadError)
```

I have tried giving a relative path based on what I learned from 'gem environment'...

```
require "./gems/pony-1.4"
```

and also

```
require "./gems/pony-1.4/lib/pony.rb"
```

to no avail.
After spent hours trying to get ActionMailer to work, I hunted down Pony as an alternative but so far I can't even get it to load.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Anyone got some love for me on this? Beuller? Beuller?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check if you have multiple ruby installations. I've had the same problem installing Ruby on a machine declared as a client in CHEF : chef installed its own ruby and libraries and, even if my script was able to load pony, it didn't while executed by CHEF.

Check if you don't any other "gem" command installed somewhere, and use it to "gem install pony".